# What is a data stream in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

Why do you talk in terms of Kafka about data streams.

Whereas for example in terms of REST API I never heard anything like data stream.

Maybe someone can tell me what the term data stream really means in Kafka.
By the way I understand that there is a producer and a consumer in Kafka. The producer
sends data to the broker and the broker sends it to the consumer.

Comment: Are you asking about *topics* or the *Kafka Streams client API*? I don't think "data stream" is ever a term used in the official documentation. Also brokers do not "push" to send data, consumers request and poll it

Answer (score 1):

Data streams in Kafka means the endless collection of data.

> For example, if you want to return all twitter messages for yesterday,
> then it is a collection with certain (although very large) number.

But if you want to return all twitter message since 1 January 2021, then it is an endless stream of data (because you didn't specify the end of period).

> If you create Kafka Consumer and subscribe to all twitter messages
> since 1 January 2021, then you will have an endless stream, which will
> return new data continuously.

You can also talk about endless data Streams in reactive REST API, why not?
If your Kafka Consumer will put all twitter messages in MongoDB, for example, which is reactive database, then you can create Web Socket connection to your reactive REST endpoint, which will continuously push new twitter messages from MongoDB to your UI.

Instead of MongoDB you can also use Kafka directly, but you will not be able to store the large amount of data during a long time (depends on you Kafka cluster configuration).

Unfortunately, most of the relational databases, like MySQL or PostgreSQL are not reactive yet, so you would have to build polling workarounds to enable reactive-like endless stream of data.

Comment: _MySQL or PostgreSQL are not reactive yet_ - reading the binlogs, like with Debezium, they can be

Comment: Does Kafka use HTTP for embedding the messages ??? Which in turn is then transported with TCP ??

Comment: @Haily Kafka uses a binary protocol over TCP. You can find more information in this article: https://kafka.apache.org/protocol.html . HTTP also uses TCP, but the main difference is that HTTP is synchronous. If you send request, you must wait for the response. Messaging systems like Kafka are asynchronous: you send message to Kafka broker and don't wait for the response, which increases performance, but makes your system more complex. Depending on your situation, you should decide for yourself: should you use asynchronous or synchronous interaction.

Comment: @Haily Also, if you want to load messages to Web UI, you must use HTTP, wrapped around Kafka or Database. The main difference here is should you use Reactive or Blocking HTTP. With Blocking HTTP, all interaction on the backend happens in one Thread, which might impact performance, because for each IO operation (retrieving file or data from database) your Thread doesn't do anything, just waits. Reactive HTTP improves performance by managing threads and in combination with web-sockets, "pushes" new data to your UI. Not all HTTP servers support Reactive HTTP, but Netty, for example, is reactive.

Comment: ok thanks. Can you describe very shortly what is a "Binary protocol"  ? I just looked at your link but I do not have time to invest many hours to read it :)

Comment: @Haily On a low level, binary protocol is a package of zeros and ones. :) 0101001000101010
Every package has limited size, and by using special agreement, Kafka knows how to treat each package. For example, if first five digits correspond to101010, then it means, that next 8 digits will be integer. Kafka uses TCP to send these packages, and it actually uses AVRO binary protocol, for translating binary data to Kafka messages. As far as I know, HTTP uses text data over TCP. Binary data are more compact and faster to exchange, than text data, so Kafka has much better performance, than HTTP.